# Tail recursion to loop

Tags: python, math, tail-recursion

I as working on a program that given a and b, computes the last 5 digits of a^b. I currently have it working as long as b is sufficiently low, but if b is large (>1000) this will crush the stack. Is there a way I can make this an iterative function? I have tried converting to iterative, but I can't figure it out.

```
def pow_mod(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    elif b == 2:
        return a*a % 10000
    return ((b%2*(a-1) + 1) * pow_mod(a,b//2)**2) % 10000
```

Comment: Your code isn't doing tail recursion, because it multiplies the value of the recursive call.

Comment: Tail recursion would look like `return pow_mod(...)`, not `return something * pow_mod(...)`

Comment: Not that it matters, because Python doesn't do tail recursion optimization.

Comment: is there a way I could make this tail recursive (something like adding a first param for the current amount?

Comment: Since Python doesn't optimize tail recursion, you'll still get the same blowout.

Comment: This will be fine as long as `b` is not greater than `2**1000` because the algorithm is logarithmic in complexity. `pow_mod(2**1000000, 2**990)` works, for example. And `2**990` is big, much more than 1000.

Comment: You might be interested in the blog series ["Tricks of the trade: Recursion to Iteration" by Tom Moertel](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html).

Comment: What you are computing are the last 5 digits, not the first, leading digits. Are you sure that your understanding matches the task description?

Comment: oops, problem updated

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this computation, iteratively, you start with an answer=a, and then square it repeatedly (and multiply by a if b is odd). To exit the loop, divide b by 2 each time, and check for when b>1.

```
def pow_mod(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    c = 1;
    while b > 1:
        if b % 2:
            c *= a
        a *= a
        b //= 2
        a %= 10000
        c %=  10000
    return a * c % 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop instead of recursion, to adjust `b` the same way that you do in the recursive call.

```
def pow_mod(a, b):
    result = 1
    while b > 0:
        result = (b%2*(a-1) + 1) * result**2) % 10000
        b = b//2
    return result
```

Comment: At least currently, this is broken. pow_mod(2,even)=2 with this. It is right for odd numbers though, any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The recursion does something like this but backwards, that's what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't help that I dont really understand what the algorithm is doing.

Comment: Your answer was pretty close, I'm posting an actual answer now.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to store the result in a temporary variable and then pass it to each function call.

```
lst = []
while b:
    lst.insert(0, b)
    b = b//2

def _pow_mod(a, b, answer):
    if b == 2:
        return a*a % 10000;
    else:
        return ((b%2*(a-1) + 1) * answer **2) % 10000

answer = 1  # b = 0 case
for b in lst:
    answer = _pow_mod(a, b, answer)
```

Complete Code:

```
# Original recursive solution
def pow_mod_orig(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    elif b == 2:
        return a*a % 10000
    return ((b%2*(a-1) + 1) * pow_mod_orig(a,b//2)**2) % 10000

# Iterative solution
def pow_mod(a, b):

    lst = []
    while b:
        lst.insert(0, b)
        b = b//2

    def _pow_mod(a, b, answer):
        if b == 2:
            return a*a % 10000;
        else:
            return ((b%2*(a-1) + 1) * answer **2) % 10000

    answer = 1  # b = 0 case
    for b in lst:
        answer = _pow_mod(a, b, answer)

    return answer


for i in range(1000):
    assert(pow_mod_orig(3, i) == pow_mod(3, i))
```

Comment: some comments explaining on the downvote will help me to learn from my mistakes. Please provide some comments explaining why you down voted.